# Amazon AWS and tomcat non-stop(graceful) deployment

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, deployment, suspend, aws-cli

We have elb load balanced 2 WAS machines runnining with tomcat as application server. To achieve non-stop deployment under AWS environment, we should,

1. select a deployment target WAS.
2. make it stop incomming transactions from elb.(elb suspend)
3. wait until current transactions are done.
4. stop WAS.
5. deploy new package.
6. start WAS.
7. elb resume.

The problem is 2 and 3.
Here is the AWS CLI ELB documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/index.html

Most similar apis to do elb suspend is `deregister-instances-from-load-balancer`.

Actually, it's not suspend but get rid of a node from elb. Moreover when the node is removed, its all transactions are halted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [ELB connection draining](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-conn-drain.html). From the docs: "Connection draining causes the load balancer to stop sending new requests to the back-end instances when the instances are deregistering or when instances become unhealthy, while ensuring that in-flight requests continue to be served."